# Grails bitwise operators

Tags: grails, groovy, bitwise-operators

can anybody shed some light on my problem with bitwise operators in Grails (or groovy, for that matter)?

I'm trying to use a domain class property with flags and here's what I've tried so far - none of them work:

```
manager.memberOf &= 0x04

manager.memberOf = manager.memberOf & 0x04

manager.memberOf = manager.memberOf.and(0x04)
```

any ideas? I'm totally clueless...

TIA,
sphere

ps: manager.memberOf is an Integer type and has a default value of 0 (zero)

ps2: memberOf remains zero after any of these operations

Comment: `&` is the bitwise and operator. What datatype is `memberOf`? What's the value of `memberOf` before and after the and?

Comment: Well, what's the type of `manager.memberOf`?

Comment: If you could re-write your question as a failing unit test that can be run in the groovy console it would be a lot easier to help you. Use the groovy `assert` keyword to indicate where the test is failing and what your expectations are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bitwise `&` operator takes two arguments. If any of these arguments is 0, the result will be zero. In your case the result is always 0 because one of the arguments (the initial value of `manager.memberOf`) is 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a bit, you have to use the OR operator (union).

```
def MANAGER = 0x04
manager.memberOf |= MANAGER
```

then, when you want to check if a flag is enabled, first you have to get only the bit from the byte using the same mask with the AND operator (intersection) and compare with the mask. If it's the same as the mask, the bit was enabled, if it's 0, the bit was disabled.

```
(manager.memberOf & MANAGER) == MANAGER
```

Full working example:

```
def MANAGER = 1
def ADMIN = 2
def CLIENT = 4

def manager = [memberOf:0]

// Add to the MANAGER
manager.memberOf |= MANAGER


assert (manager.memberOf & MANAGER) == MANAGER
assert (manager.memberOf & ADMIN) == 0
assert (manager.memberOf & CLIENT) == 0​
```